# Is it possible to make a Java project to executable file?

Tags: netbeans, javafx, javafx-2, executable

I have done a project in JavaFX. I used NetBeans IDE to do my project. I used MySQL as database. Currently I run my project with the help of NetBeans. Is there any way to make the project an executable file ?

What I meant by executable is to launch the project by double clicking on it. Suggest me some good and easy methods, with tutorial if possible.

Comment: Read the [Oracle JavaFX deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans has a folder for their projects. (Default: documents/NetbeansProjects)

There you will find your project.

First, click on the Clean and Build button inside netbeans.

Then you can find a .jar file in your project folder's dist folder.

Comment: Can I run that jar file in any system if it has no NetBeans installed in it ?

Comment: If it has java installed on the system, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

What you are thinking of is a **self-contained** javafx application. Nifty guide [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm).

This is an .exe file (on windows, i tried it on kubuntu and it builds a nice .deb and a separate executable). You can place this executable somewhere else and it will work, even if no java is installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Launch4j to create executable file.

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/